# Injeção de dependência MVC C# - MongoDB 2.0

Tags: c#, design-pattern, mongodb, injeção-de-dependência, mongodb-csharp

Estou iniciando em um projeto utilizando `MVC 4` com Driver 2.0 do `MongoDB`.
Estou habituado a utilizar `Ninject` com `EF6` e gostaria de saber se existe algo do tipo para `MongoDB`ou algum padrão de arquitetura de exemplo para implementação do mesmo.

Ps: Já encontrei alguns exemplos utilizando o driver antigo, porém estou implementando o novo do `MongoDB`.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

### MongoDB Driver Dependency Injection

O driver do `MongoDB` é fortemente acoplado ou seja você não vai conseguir modificar as funcionalidades do driver de forma fácil visto que ele não utiliza dependências externas(Você certamente não está tentando fazer isso), se você pretende utilizar o `MongoDB` através de um sistema de injeção de dependência você precisará implementar ou transferir objetos com base nas interfaces abaixo:

**MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient**:
Interface responsável por especificar um cliente do mongodb irá te permitir o acesso aos métodos de gestão do banco de dados(criação de novos bancos, deleção e listagem, obtenção de um único banco)
Referência: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoClient.htm

**MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase**:
Interface responsável por especificar uma coleção do mongodb irá te permitir o acesso aos métodos de gestão das coleções(criação, deleção e listagem, obtenção, renomeação e execução de comandos)
Referência: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase.htm

**MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<>**:
Interface responsável por especificar coleções de documentos do mongo diferente das demais interfaces as coleções são genericas ou seja você terá de especificar um tipo para as coleções Ex: IMongoCollection< Produto> as coleções vão lhe permitir o acesso aos registros através dos métodos de consulta, deleção, edição, inserção, dentre outros.
Referência: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1.htm

---

Quanto a um pattern para se utilizar, segue um exemplo de implementação do `Repository Pattern` com MongoDB:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : new()
{
    protected readonly MongoClient client;
    protected readonly MongoServer server;
    protected readonly MongoDatabase database;
    protected readonly MongoCollection collection;


    public Repository(MongoClient client, MongoServer server, MongoDatabase database, MongoCollection collection)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.server = server;
        this.database = database;
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    // Exemplo de adição de novos elementos em uma coleção.
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        this.collection.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

Créditos a https://github.com/fagnercarvalho pelo código referente ao repositório

Comment: Obrigado Felipe pela colaboração. Porém não queria fazer a reescrita das interfaces do mongo para injeção. Referente ao repositório obrigado pela dica porém já estou utilizando um Repositório Genérico também no projeto.

Comment: Você não precisa implementar as interfaces basta registar as classes concretas do mongo em seu container.